# Single EC2 behind ELB creates massive latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a Flask API running on a single EC2 instance. I need to add SSL (https) to my app  and the docs seem to indicate that the best way is to use ELB.

The problem is when I set up the EC2 behind the ELB and with a Route 53 pointing to the load balancer, I get latency issues like never before. API calls that should take 150ms, take 31s. If I ping the EC2 directly, there is no issue, but pinging the Route53/ELB takes too long.

I've looked at past responses such as these:

> The reason for the delay is because you have the ELB setup for
> multi-az without any application instances in the other 2 AZ's
> configured. Without instances in those AZ's requests will tend to fail
> because the ELb still returns IP addresses for those AZ's even if
> there are no active application instances. Please disable the other
> AZ's for now and continue your tests.

So I deleted the subnets and AZs that are not related to my EC2 instance, but now I have:
`503 errors: Backend server is at capacity` all over the place.

About to pull my hair out. All I am trying to do it setup SSL for my app...

Comment: Have you got cross-zone load balancing disabled?

Comment: Yep. I disabled that as now I have only one zone in the ELB.

Comment: If you have it enabled does the latency decrease?

Comment: Latency is still the same with cross zone enabled. Interestingly if I set up the ELB to have multiple AZs, I never the the 503 error, but latency is still an issue.

Comment: Can you check in CloudWatch metrics for the load balancer for the TargetLatency metric. That should help you to identify whether the latency is on the host or the LB

Comment: They seem to indicate periodic unhealthy hosts (i.e. the sole host that I have). Also when I ping the EC2 IP directly, there is NO latency, so I am convinced this is something related to the ELB setup...

Comment: It looks like the problem is occurring in consecutive requests. The first request is responded to quickly, but the next request if sent right after is failing. Looks like ELB is trying to rate limit even though the app can handle it. How can I go about removing this rate limit?

Comment: Could it be an issue with the Health Check? See: [Amazon EC2 Web server in Load Balancer gives 503](https://serverfault.com/a/602174/267968)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, using the **Application Load Balancer** instead of the **Classic Load Balancer** has resolved this latency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some connectivity issue. Follow this step to drill down the issue. As its happening from load balancer only. So first do the NSLOOKUP like nslookup  name. You will get minimum two IP.

Try to individual curl LB IP's n check the response time. You may use below command or perhaps any of your fav tool.

```
curl -w "dns_resolution: %{time_namelookup}, \
         tcp_established: %{time_connect}, \
         ssl_handshake_done: %{time_appconnect}, \
         TTFB: %{time_starttransfer}\n" \
         -o /dev/null -s "http://<ELB IP>/<path>"
```

This way you be figure out whether is the issue. It be due to routing issue on one specific AZ subnet, or some other issue.